# Discard build in case of failure

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm creating a custom build process template that allows the person who is queueing the build to define the build and revision numbers (as they are used on the assembly version info).

However, if the build fails, they can't queue a new build for the same version (but they should be able).

Is there a way to automatically discard the build if any step in the workflow or MSBuild Script fails?

Comment: Surely, if it's a different build, it *should* have a different build number - how else would you reconcile whether a bug is fixed in that build number, if it could refer to multiple builds?

Comment: I'm asking this because we are doing some tests with the new build definition and in some situations it is causing errors (not because of the project source code), so I need to discard the build, fix the build definition and queue a build using the same build number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the features added in TFS 2012 is the a[bility to retry a build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722(v=vs.110).aspx#Retry).

This allows you to right click a failed build and select retry instead of queuing a new build. This should allow you to run a build with the same configuration settings without getting errors on your build numbers.

Answer (score 1):

TFS maintains assigned build numbers in the database itself, for its own administrative purposes. This maintains its internal consistency with all the assets that are produced and (intermediate) work products.

The only way to free up a previously used build number is to actively DESTROY it from the database. Please see http://geekswithblogs.net/jehan/archive/2011/04/23/tf42064-the-build-number-already-exists-for-build-definition-error.aspx for a further explaination.